# Understanding access_process_vm linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory

I am writing a kernel module which reads parts of the virtual memory of a process. I am trying to use the access_process_vm method in the kernel to do so, but it always ends up reading 0 bytes.

```
  target = get_pid_task(find_get_pid(target_pid),PIDTYPE_PID);
  if (target == NULL) {
      printk(KERN_ALERT "no such task %d\n",target_pid);
      return -1;
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "opened task with pid %d\n",target->pid);

  len = vm_end-vm_start;
  buf = kmalloc(len ,GFP_KERNEL);
  if (!buf) {
      printk(KERN_ALERT "unable to allocate memory\n");
      return -1;
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "allocated memory\n");

  bytes = access_process_vm(target,addr,buf,len,FOLL_FORCE);
  if (bytes != len) {
       printk(KERN_ALERT "could only read %d of %ld bytes\n",bytes,len);
       kfree(buf);
       return -1;
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "read %d bytes successfully\n",bytes);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's the problem tracking this down.

Let's take a look at first 2 failure modes in access_process_vm itself:

```
   if (addr + len < addr)
            return 0;
```

You compute the len based on vm_end and vm_start, but you read starting from addr. What's up with the discrepancy? Perhaps you end up failing this check?

```
   mm = get_task_mm(tsk);
   if (!mm)        
           return 0;
```

How about this? What if there is no mm?

And so on.

Also note you are returning -1 instead of an actual error. You are leaking a reference to the target thread on error.